# how to get a selected value from a dropdown list

Tags: angular, spring-boot, select, data-binding

I am working on a backend application in spring boot and frontend in angular 5.
I have a drop-down list. 
here is the code forthe list .

```
<select #selectElem (change)="onSelectCat($event.target.value)" >

<option *ngFor="let categorie of categories" [value]="fournisseur.categorieid" id="categorieid" name="categorieid">
{{categorie.libelle}}
</option>
</select>
```

and I want to retrieve the selected value from the list and add it with the provider object that the form sends by clicking the button add who calls this function : add.component.ts

```
newUser(fournisseur){
  this.fournService.createFourn(this.fournisseur).subscribe((fournisseur)=>{
    console.log(fournisseur);
   // this.router.navigate(['/*/listsuppliers'])
  },(error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

any ideas , thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try please `[(ngModel)] = "fournisseur.categorieid"` for `select` element and change `[value]="fournisseur.categorieid"` to `[value]="categorie?.categorieid"`in `option`. Here https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel example how use ngModel in select element